# Parsing xml ListBoxs with WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, xml-parsing

I'm working on an application that shows for everyday a list of shows for a certain Tv channel.
My problem is that the xml from which i'm extracting my data has the form below, and i want my Phone page to display the days'names (mon,tue,thu,fri...) in the top and below the list of programs for the selected day.
I want to read all the "date" and "item" at  the same time, but all i can read is all "date" or all "item" but not both at the same time ( i used the methods below):
c#:
"item"
`
var items = from item in doc.Elements("programme").Descendants("item")

```
 select new ProgData
   {
     Time = item.Element("heure").Value,
     Title = item.Element("title").Value,
     Photo = item.Element("image").Value,
     Description = ((item.Element("description").Value).Length > maxLength ? (item.Element("description").Value).Substring(0, maxLength) : (item.Element("description").Value)),

   }; ProgsListBox.ItemsSource = items;`
```

"date":

```
 var items = from c in doc.Elements("programme").Descendants("jour")
             select new Week()
             {
               Day = c.Attribute("date").Value,
              Date = (DateTime.Parse(c.Attribute("date").Value)).DayOfWeek,
             }; ListBoxDays.ItemsSource = items;
```

xml:

```
<programs>
<day date="04/01/2012">
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>PROGRAM ONE</title>
        <image>
        http://www.tvchannel.tv/uploads/show/thumbnails_iphone/programone-copy.png
        </image>
        <description>
        <![CDATA[ Infos about my show ]]>
        </description>
        <corps>
        <![CDATA[ Just more infos about my show ]]>
        <![CDATA[more and more infos]]>
        </corps>
        <heure>00:00</heure>
        <link/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>PROGRAM TWO</title>
        <image>
        http://www.tvchannel.tv/uploads/show/thumbnails_iphone/progratwo-copy.png
        </image>
        <description>
        <![CDATA[ Infos about my show ]]>
        </description>
        <corps>
        <![CDATA[ Just more infos about my show ]]>
        <![CDATA[more and more infos]]>
        </corps>
        <heure>06:00</heure>
        <link/>
    </item>
</day>
    <day date="05/01/2012">
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>PROGRAM ONE</title>
        <image>
        http://www.tvchannel.tv/uploads/show/thumbnails_iphone/programone-copy.png
        </image>
        <description>
        <![CDATA[ Infos about my show ]]>
        </description>
        <corps>
        <![CDATA[ Just more infos about my show ]]>
        <![CDATA[more and more infos]]>
        </corps>
        <heure>00:00</heure>
        <link/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>PROGRAM TWO</title>
        <image>
        http://www.tvchannel.tv/uploads/show/thumbnails_iphone/progratwo-copy.png
        </image>
        <description>
        <![CDATA[ Infos about my show ]]>
        </description>
        <corps>
        <![CDATA[ Just more infos about my show ]]>
        <![CDATA[more and more infos]]>
        </corps>
        <heure>06:00</heure>
        <link/>
    </item>
</day>
```

Phone Page:
[image: The expected resul]

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the date from dd/mm/yyyy to day names or how to parse the above XML (and convert the date in the process)?

Comment: I'm asking how to parse the day part of xml and convert it at the same time(converting it when i'm parsing it).

Comment: I want to parse two listBoxs at the same time :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have a `DateTime` object and you need to show day of the week instead?

Use `DayOfWeek` of `DateTime` class in switch statement to get a string representation (Sun, Mon, etc.) that you need.

Comment: But how can i extract it from my xml?

Comment: Create class hierarchy that represent xml and use linq to fill it. When you grab `DateTime` from xml, you can find day of week then. http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/introduction-to-linq-simple-xml-parsing

Answer (score 0):

Parse your Date from your xml into a DateTime and then you can simply use DayOfWeek property.

[MSDN DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx)

Comment: Do you mean like that:`Day=(item.Element("jour").Attribute("date").Value).ToString("ddd"),`?!

Comment: I can not read all the days, my code display only the first date, is that normal? Isn't there a solution?HELP!!!

Comment: @MarTech probably your xml parsing doesn't work correctly! How do you parse your xml?

Comment: Actually i didn't know how to filter data, i tried this method but there's an issue with it and i can't find how to fix it.

Comment: 'var doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(e.Result));
              var items = from c in doc.Elements("programme").Descendants("jour") where c.Attribute("date").Value=="19/02/2012"

                          select new Tutorial()
                           {
                             
Time = c.Element("heure").Value,
 Title = c.Element("title").Value,
 Photo = c.Element("image").Value,
 Description=c.Element("description").Value,
                          };
                            ListBoxDays.ItemsSource = items;'